# Using Task Scheduler to run a batch file that contains the start /w command

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp, scheduled-tasks, runas

I have a Windows XP virtual machine that I am using to run a legacy app. I am using a limited user account.

I have created a batch file that I'd like to:

1. Start the legacy app
2. Wait for the program in step 1 to close
3. Shut down the computer

So this is the code I am using (in this example, I am attempting to open notepad):

```
@ECHO OFF
start /w notepad
%windir%\system32\shutdown.exe -f -s -t 1
```

Because the legacy app needs to be run under an account with administrator privileges, I then manually created a scheduled task in Task Scheduler to run the batch file. The scheduled task is set to run using an account named Admin that has administrator privileges.

I am having a bit of an issue. When the scheduled task runs, nothing appears on the screen. However, I did notice that both cmd.exe and notepad.exe appear in Task Manager as processes running as the user Admin.

What am I doing wrong? How can I accomplish what I'd like to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all, it was an issue with me not having Task Scheduler set up properly. I found [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/327491/how-to-make-the-task-scheduler-display-the-cmd-shell-when-invoking-a-batch-file) which suggests to use the AT command to run the task interactively. This allows the Cmd window to be displayed when a batch file is run as a Scheduled Task.